# Debug Typescript (or JavaScript) with a "Web Site Project" in Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to get an Aurelia project working in Visual Studio.  I followed the steps outlined [here](https://github.com/jtrefry/aurelia-typescript-vs2015) and it builds and runs correctly.

This process has me using a **"Web Site Project"** (Not a Web Application Project).  This is so that the tsconfig.json file can be used.

While it runs just fine, I cannot find a way to debug.  (Meaning set a breakpoint and have the the app break and let me step through the code.)

Is Typescript/JavaScript debugging not supported with Web Site Projects?  (I am using VS 2015).

**If is supported for Web Site Projects, then I would love a suggestion on how to enable it or troubleshoot it.**

Answer (score 0):

Debugging in VS in general is only supported with Internet Explorer. If you tried an other browser (edge?), that may be your problem.